# Navbar hiding text after clicking on anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I've recently been using Twitter Bootstrap, and I've been loving it.

I've created a navbar that is fixed to the top, and inside it is my logo, a header, a few links, and a dropdown that says "Jump to:". Upon clicking on the dropdown, a menu comes down with four links to a section within the page. All of the links work.

My problem is that because the header of each section is now placed at the top of my page, my fixed navbar blocks it. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening? A bit of jQuery or something?

This is my website: [fishyfishy2014.gweb.io](http://fishyfishy2014.gweb.io). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking about an anchor jump, which will place the matching anchor to the top of the viewport and "under" the fixed nav. I had a similar issue and used this code:

```
/* fixing anchor jumps */

var nav_height = 77; // pixels

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e){
    if($(location.hash).hasClass('anchor')){
        scrollBy(0, nav_height);
    }
    return false;
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(location.hash).hasClass('anchor')){
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(location.hash).offset().top - nav_height - 10
        }, 10 );
    }
});
```

You just have to add the `anchor` CSS class to any element, you want be able to jump to.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I've added the the code under the jQuery file, and I've taken out the "px" in your `nav_height` variable. I've added the `anchor` class to the the `<a>` tag surrounding my header, but it still doesn't seem to work. I've updated the website. Feel free to click on "View page source" to see what I've got wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, there is also the scroll-margin-top property that sets the element's scroll margin to the top side.
You need to apply to anchored element a class, for exemple .anchor
After that, you can apply this :

```
.anchor {
    scroll-margin-top: 77px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this:

`body { padding-top: 70px; }`

This is coming from the Bootstrap docs itself

> Body padding required The fixed navbar will overlay your other
>   content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your
>   own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is
>   50px high.

You can check [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Comment: He is not asking about the content itself being hidden under the navigation, but after a click on an anchor link.

Comment: @Kau-Boy : I see, I guess an edit to the Question Title will help also. Thank you for clarifying that one.

Answer (score 1):

The following works without any JS:

```css
a:not([href]):before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 60px;
    margin: -60px 0 0;
}
```

`a:not([href])` assumes that your anchors don't have a `href` attribute. Change both occurrences of 60px to a value of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 2ndkauboy's solution does work. In short:

1. get rid of the 'px' in `nav_height` variable (...as you said)
2. use the `anchor` css class (...as 2ndkauboy said) but DONOT use it on the `<a>` tag but on the `<div>`, as follows:

   `<a href="#jump_here">click here</a>
   ... other code here ...
   <div id="jump_here" class="anchor">
       ... content ...
   </div>`

Hope it helps.